# return data from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I have this function

```
function get_last(){
                $.ajax({
                        url:'fronta.php?get_last&last=1',
                        success:function(data) {
                                var last = parseInt(data);

                        }

                });
                return last;

}
```

but when I call it like

```
var last = get_last();
alert(last);
```

firebug gives me "last is not defined"

How can I pass this last variable into global scope ?

Comment: Try defining `var last;` before the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you are calling AJAX asynchrosnously so dont expect you can get the value from ajax response and return it.

Second thing is var last is defined in success handler's scope so in order to access any variable it should be defined in a proper scope.

If you want you can call ajax sychronously in order to get the response and return it.

```
    function get_last(){
var last = null;
                    $.ajax({
                            url:'fronta.php?get_last&last=1',.
                            success:function(data) {
                                    last = parseInt(data);

                            },
                            async: false

                    });
                    return last;

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't async be set to false if he wants the last variable set before the method returns?

Comment: your solution gives me "null"

Comment: but with async: false it does froze whole browser. Can I do it with async:true ?

Comment: I thought success: callback is called AFTER ajax is done. Isn't that true?

Comment: if you want to return the response form AJAX call you have to make it async false.

Comment: Yes the browser will stop responding for a sec untill the response comes. Otherwise you might have to change your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

```
function get_last(){
    var last;
    $.ajax({
        url:'fronta.php?get_last&last=1',
        async: false,
        success:function(data) {
            last = parseInt(data);
        }
    });
    return last;
}
```

Move the declaration of the `last` variable to the parent function, instead of having it in the callback. In JavaScript, inner functions have access to variables declared in their parent, so `last = parseInt(data);` will update the variable declared in the parent function.

Also note that you will have to run this synchronously, otherwise the function will return before the response is handled.

Also, it may have been a typo when you wrote the question, but there's a random `.` character at the end of your `url:'fronta...` line. You need to get rid of that.

Comment: async, last will not be set this way

Comment: If it didn't work, maybe ht eissue is not with your jquery, but with what your php file is returning? Have you tried to debug with firebug or something like that?

Comment: @genesis - See my update (last paragraph). If you have that `.` character in your actual code, it will probably break.

Comment: @Joe Tuskan - good point, answer updated. @genesis - Note my latest edit, the addition of the `async: false`.